# Import database from MSSQL export dump on Ubuntu localhost

Tags: sql-server, import, ubuntu, export, sqlcmd

I have an export file from an online database server that I need to use to generate the database locally on my system. I'm running MSSQL 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04.

The export file has `Program(application/octet-stream)` in file properties dialogue box.

I want to use this file with SQLCMD command-line tool. Is it possible? If yes, how to do it? Please inform me if there's anything else I can specify before closing this question, if it seems vague or anything.

Comment: What is the file extension of your export file?

Comment: @dbdemon It didn't have any extension. I added `.bak` myself. It's working fine on Windows now. On Ubuntu, it says `can't access the directory. OS error`. I believe I need to login SQL Server as my yser to be able to access the filesystem. Anyways, that's a separate issue. This one's solved I believe. Just need to find out how to login as user with FS access now. Thanks for the trying to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the export dump file didn't have any extension and the SQLCMD couldn't recognize the file and didn't accept it.

I added the a `.bak` extension to the file and the SQL Server Management Tool restored the database from this modified file. It's still doesn't work on Ubuntu but that's a permissions problem. I'll maybe ask a separate question or look for it if it's already asked.